# Data is being echo'd 3 times instead of once

Tags: php, sql, echo

Hi any help would be appreciated as i cant seem to find the error that is causing my data to be replicated and echo'd to the user 3 times instead of once. If anyone could help me solve this issue thanks.

```
<?php

session_start();
//Connect to database 

if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])) { //check if user-name is not given

    echo('you are not authorised to veiw this page, log in with admin account to view it');

    //show login page
    include 'login.html';
}
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost:3307","root","usbw","degreeproject");

//check if query sucessful else report error
$classid = $_GET['classid'];
$studentid = $_GET['userid'];
$sql3 = "SELECT usernames.username, quizzes.QuizID, results.score, results.QuizID,enrolledclasses.UserID, quizzes.ClassID FROM `results`, enrolledclasses, usernames, quizzes 
                WHERE usernames.username = results.username
                AND quizzes.QuizID = results.QuizID             
                AND enrolledclasses.UserID = $studentid
                AND quizzes.ClassID = $classid;";


if (!$result3=mysqli_query($con,$sql3)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}       
else {
    //count the number of records from the query result
    $count=mysqli_num_rows($result3);
}   

if($count>=1) {
    $result3 = mysqli_query($con,$sql3); 
    while(list($Username, $QuizID, $Score) = mysqli_fetch_row($result3)) {
            $sql = "SELECT COUNT(Question) as total FROM questions WHERE QuizID = $QuizID";
            $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
            $numquestions;
            if($result->num_rows > 0) {
                $numquestions = $result->fetch_assoc()['total'];
            }

            echo"<table>";
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th>Username: </th>";
                echo "<th>QuizID: </th>";
                echo "<th>Score: </th>";
                echo "<th>Go Back: </th>";
            echo "</tr>";

            echo "<tr>";
            echo("<td>$Username</td>");
            echo("<td>$QuizID</td>");
            echo("<td>$Score / $numquestions</td>");
            echo("<td></td>");
            echo "<td><a href ='../CurrentlyBeingWorkedOn/index.php'> Go Back Home &nbsp; &nbsp;</a></td>";
            echo"</tr>";
            echo"</table>";
        }
    }


$con->query($sql3);

echo("<p>Successfully Retrieved The Results For The Quizzes Students Have Taken.</p>");
echo("<p><a href='javascript:history.back(1);'>Return To Previous Page</a></p>");



?>
```

this is the results of the code and what is outputted to the user.

[Resulting Output][1]  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hn5jm.png

Comment: `<table></table>` is inside the while loop for one thing, unless that's what you want.

Comment: It's supposed to echo a new table of results for each result that is found based on the query i also have the same code with my tables within the loop on other pages and it does not cause this issue.

Comment: usually it's b/c of a SQL issue, your joins are probably causing extra data to return, and then your code is looping over the set. Can you run just the sql in the database and see the raw results?

Comment: I am able to run the SQL on my Database apart from the last line as it relies on a variable, but this is the output of PHPMyAdmin when i run the SQL on the server. Img of MySQL output: https://gyazo.com/b45ee9bbf59db5e54b1614fb9bd70a48

Comment: Print your `$count` and have a look on how much results you get. I can imagine, that your joins cause redundant data.

Comment: I have echo'd $count and it prints 6 so this is the cause of my redundant data i just dont know why.

Comment: So your query in the MySQL output does not match the $sql3 query, have you tried changing the $sql3 query to the one in your phpMyAdmin?

Comment: MySQL query has been copied from the PHP and this displays what i put in the Gyazo link it echo's those results however it is echo'ing 6 results back even though there should be only two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from what i see there is a problem in your joining condition. there are relation between username and result, quizzes and results. but there is no relationship between enrolledclasses with any other tables. add the relationship in the where clause you will find your desired output.

```
SELECT usernames.username, quizzes.QuizID, results.score, results.QuizID,enrolledclasses.UserID, quizzes.ClassID FROM `results`, enrolledclasses, usernames, quizzes 
WHERE usernames.username = results.username
AND quizzes.QuizID = results.QuizID
AND enrolledclasses.UserID = usernames.UserID          
AND enrolledclasses.ClassID= quizzes.ClassID          
AND enrolledclasses.UserID = $studentid
AND quizzes.ClassID = $classid;
```

Comment: How do you mean this ?

Comment: sorry. didn't get what you asked?

Comment: How would i put the relationship in the where statement as i have tried to put enrolledclasses.UserID = usernames.UserID and it didn't work.

Comment: OK, then can you show me the structure of quizzes and results table. you might also need to add relationship with this table.

Comment: QuizID Structure - https://gyazo.com/327decf7049bded2c1e7c401fc99d658
Results Structure - https://gyazo.com/8fd565858db2de8446b68c77d5e0528f 

let me know if you need the relational view

Comment: check my current query. let me know if this helps

Comment: Thank you so much this query now works successfully and as intended for my system!

Comment: happy to help. :D

Comment: Thanks alot been confused as to why this wasn't working all day so you've been a massive help thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to rewrite you SQL query using explicit `JOIN` statements:

```
"SELECT usernames.username, quizzes.QuizID, results.score,
    results.QuizID,enrolledclasses.UserID, quizzes.ClassID 
FROM usernames u 
    JOIN results r ON u.username=r.username 
    JOIN quizzes q ON q.QuizID=r.QuizID 
    JOIN enrolledclasses ec ON ec.?=?.? 
WHERE q.ClassID = $classid AND ec.UserID=$studentid"
```

You need a join-criteria for your enrolledclasses table I can't see from your given code - maybe you can join it to the `users`-table on the username or something like that? Simply replace the questionmarks in the code given above. If you don't have any criteria you can join on, you have to introduce one in the `enrolledclasses`-table.

Comment: I have a userID within the enrolled table aswell as the users table would that be best to join from?

Comment: `ec.userID=u.userID`

Comment: Current Error being shown after inputting the SQL code - https://gyazo.com/1f91d44729b9c820b8bf23ba7b792090

Comment: Your `Username` column is written uppercase. Sorry is a copy and paste error from your initial query. Replace all occurences of `username` with `Username`

Comment: On other code I have written doesn't include it in Upper Case and it works however

Comment: I have changed it to upper case and it is still giving me the same error

Comment: Whatever - if upper solution works for you, everything's fine ;)

Comment: Yeah the above solution fixed it for me when i was changing it from upper to lowercase it still gave me the same issues.